# freemarker templates: split large string in n-size chunks

Tags: java, string, freemarker

I would like to split a long string into N-size chunks in a freemarker template.

How could this be done with freemarker instruments?

Example:
String - `"1234567890"`
Chunk size - `3`
Result - `["123", "456", "789", "0"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done with regular expressions, using the `matches` built-in (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_matches):

```
<#list someString?matches('.{1,3}', 's') as chunk>
- ${chunk}
</#list>
```

I have listed the chunks here, but of course you could do `<#assign chunks = someString?matches('.{1,3}', 's')>` as well.

Put it into a `#function` if you need this often.

The `'s'` is the dot-all flag (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_string_flags).

Comment: Note: it's build in since v2.3.3.
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_chunk

Comment: Just in case someone still uses 2.3.2 from 2005-01-22? (: Though... anything can happen.